# How to print something when the user reaches a specific point in the page? (not dependant on any class or ID element)

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I want to print something in the console log when the user reaches a certain point in the page. I want it to appear regardless of the classes or IDs of the page, just when it reaches a speciifc point and not to be repeated, specially not to repeat if the user goes up and scrolls down again.

In this example, if I use `$this.scrollTop() > 400` it does work, but the console keeps repeating the message. So I thought using `==` instead, but it won't work.

Why? How can I get that sorted? Can this be achieved with vanilla JS?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $head = $('#head');
    if ($this.scrollTop() == 400) {
       console.log('You've reached 400 already');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `>` vs `==` (or `===`) has no effect on the "one time only" logic you are trying to achieve. However, it is probably safer to use `>`, as browsers may not report every single pixel change when scrolling. What you're missing is some kind of state: that tracks if that comparison has been done before.

If you only want to compare a single scroll position, then we can simply store if the user has scrolled past that point in a variable and check it, so we don't log to the console more than once:

```js
var hasPassedPoint = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.scrollTop() > 400 && !hasPassedPoint) {
    console.log('You\'ve reached 400 already');
    hasPassedPoint = true;
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
```

If you want to compare **multiple** scroll positions though, that storing these state/checkpoints in an object might make more sense:

```js
var passedCheckpoints = {};
var checkpoints = [150, 400, 550];

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  checkpoints.forEach(x => {
    if ($this.scrollTop() > x && !passedCheckpoints[x]) {
      console.log(`You've reached ${x} already`);
      passedCheckpoints[x] = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
<p>Keep scrolling down</p>
```

Comment: Excellent and clear explanation @Terry, thanks!!